# D3 horizontal stacked bar chart add and remove data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a simple horizontal D3 stacked bar graph. I use a drop down menu to select different data sets in order to update the chart values.

If ds1 and ds2 have the same number of datum i.e. ds1 has 2 data points and ds2 has 2 data points, the transition is smooth and my values are updated nicely.

However, if I have two data sets with a differing number of data points i.e. ds1 has 3 data points and ds2 has only 2 or perhaps 4 data points, I can not get the Enter, Update and Exit to work correctly.

I think this is something to do with the D3 stack function which converts the values to objects which do not form part of the update and exit methods in D3.

Most grateful if you can show me what I should do?   My full code pasted below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Update horizontal stacked bar chart</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">   
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
             <div >
                  <select id="dropdown" onchange="updateData()">

                      <!--need blank value in order to have title in selection-->

                      <option value="ds1">ds1</option>
                      <option value="ds2">ds2</option>
                      <option value="ds3">ds3</option>
                      <option value="ds4">ds4</option>
                  </select>
              </div>        


      <script type="text/javascript">

            var w = 1500,
                    h = 300;

                var rectW = 100 * 5;

                var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                            .range(["#1459D9", "#daa520","#F7C319"]);


    var ds1 = [[{x:0,y:15}],[{x:0,y:85}]];
    var ds2 = [[{x:0,y:35}],[{x:0,y:65}]];
    var ds3 = [[{x:0,y:10}],[{x:0,y:20}],[{x:0,y:70}]];
    var ds4 = [[{x:0,y:60}]];

        //Set up stack method
        var stack = d3.layout.stack();

        //Data, stacked
        stack(ds1);

        var canvas = d3.select("body") 
                .append("svg") 
                .attr("width",w)
                .attr("height",300)        
        ;


        var appending = canvas.selectAll("q") 
                .data(ds1)                           
                .enter()                    
                .append("g")
                .style("fill", function(d,i){return color(i);})
        ;


        appending.selectAll("stackrect") 
                .data(function (d){return d;}) 
                .enter()
                .append("rect") 
                .attr("id","recth")
                .attr("x",function (d){return  (w *.50 - (rectW/2)) + d.y0 * 5 ;}) 

                .attr("y",90)
                .attr("width",function (d){return (d.y * 5 );})
                .attr("height",50);       




        function updateData() {

        stack(eval("("+dropdown.value+")")); 

        appending.data(eval("("+dropdown.value+")"));


        //ds1 and ds2 equal number of datum. Update works fine.
        appending.selectAll("#recth") 
                .data(function (d){return d;})
                .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 0.5)
                .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 1.0)    
                .attr("x",function (d){return  (w *.50 - (rectW/2)) + d.y0 * 5 ;}) 
                .attr("y",90)
                .attr("width",function (d){return (d.y * 5 );})
                .attr("height",50);

        //update method not working
        appending.selectAll("#recth")
             .data(function (d){return d;})
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
                .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 0.5)
                .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 1.0)    
                .attr("x",function (d){return  (w *.50 - (rectW/2)) + d.y0 * 5 ;}) 
                .attr("y",90)
                .attr("width",function (d){return (d.y * 5 );})
                .attr("height",50);               


       //exit method not working
        appending.selectAll("#recth")
        .data(function (d){return d;})     
        .exit()
        .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 0.5)
                .transition().duration(600)
                .style("opacity", 1.0)    
                .attr("x",function (d){return  (w *.50 - (rectW/2)) + d.y0 * 5 ;}) 
                .attr("y",90)
                .attr("width",function (d){return (d.y * 5 );})
                .attr("height",50)               
        .remove();        
        }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ckersch is right that you should be using a `class` instead of an `id`. [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is what the HTML5 spec says about it, which is pretty much what every other HTML spec has said about it, that it should be unique. The fact that you have "found that id's work perfectly well in other examples" just means that you have been fortunate enough to have been using browsers that are forgiving about rendering invalid markup.

Comment: I agree with both of what you are saying. However, since in the example above I am only calling one element, it is fine to use id. I have also tried it with class, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look through the whole thing, but here's a few errors I noticed:

1) Don't use IDs as selectors for multiple things. IDs are supposed to be unique and selectors probably won't work right if you have multiple things with the same ID. Use classes instead.

2) When you add data, make sure that the things you're appending match the selector you use in the initial `selectAll()` method. For example, if you have `.selectAll('.rectClass')`, make sure you give all of the elements that you create the class `rectClass`, or the selector and data structure might not work right.

Once those are fixed, this example shows how the update/enter/exit pattern works: [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I have found that id's work perfectly well in other examples I have tried. I think the problem lies with the stack function in that it doesn't allow the data to be appended properly, because the stack function creates an initial set of objects based on the first data set. for example, if the first data set has 4 data items, then 4 objects will be created which then stick regardless of the update process.

Comment: Even if they seem to be working properly, you shouldn't use them. IDs are designed to be unique, and large portions of the core of javascript assume they are. Something will break eventually. `stack` is a function, so it doesn't care what it's been used on in the past.

Comment: I'm also not sure what this is supposed to be doing: `appending.selectAll("#recth").data(function (d){return d;})`

Comment: That selects all rectangles with the id recth. then returns their data. so if you select ds1 it returns the data for ds1 which is used to update the chart. If you select ds2 from the dropdown it selects data from ds2 and updates the chart. The thing doesn't work when the second ds (ds3 and 4 in my example) has a different number of data points to ds1. Put the code a browser and have a play.